# Can someone explain why this sentence is correct?

Tags: punctuation, commas

'The secretary of state, Boris Johnson said that...'

It has always been my understanding that there would be a comma again after Boris Johnson, but I've just read it in The Telegraph and therefore I assume it's correct? If so, it doesn't follow any comma usage rule that I know so could someone elaborate?

Comment: Drop both the comma and the initial *The* ................ especially in a journalistic context.

Comment: You're right; without an added comma, the sentence is incorrect (unless you also drop "the").

Comment: Please first quote what you actually did read in *The Daily Telegraph* -  noting that difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  A comma should be used after Johnson.  A good rule of thumb for appositives is that if they can be removed without changing the sentence they should be placed inside commas.  Boris Johnson can be removed.